# What are all Qt ui components for symbian?

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian

i want to develop symbian programm with Qt. i have to learn list of ui components in qt.

Comment: I'm surprised by people who are just starting to learn Symbian. I was going to do that a month before Nokia decided to use Windows mobile, than I dropped it. Are you sure you want to learn Symbian now that Nokia is going to use windows mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to build mobile UIs with Qt:

1. you do it the hard way with canvas and create the stuff on your own (don't do it)
2. do it with classic Qt GUI module (very unusable, targets desktop, hard to use on the phone)
3. use QtQuick (QtDeclarative/QML)...that's the way you should go.

QtQuick comes basically with not that much ui components. 
But there are some possibilities:

a. build components on your own: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/quick-components.html

b. use nokia qml templates: https://projects.developer.nokia.com/QMLTemplates

c. use the upcoming qt components for symbian: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/04/08/qt-quick-components-for-symbian-technology-preview/

Practically I think i future, the combination of Qt/QtQuick and QtCOmponents for Symbian will be the right way.

btw: Nokia will deliver more than 150 million qt devices the next year, several devices are already announced with Qt and Symbian for this year, also N9 is announced with meego so your stuff can be easily ported. Working with Qt for Symbian is for sure not that useless like some people say :-)